# Why is Chrome updating the body instead of the textarea value when using a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, textarea

I have the latest Chrome and I would like to update a `textarea` field as follows with a bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("<here comes the ID>").value="test";
```

Chrome always updates the element `body` with the value "test" (from the example above) instead of the `textarea`

You can test this by going to http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/textarea/demoframe and executing the bookmarklet with the ID of the `textarea` of that mentioned page or via the Stack Snippet below:

```css
ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>Without the void operator:</strong> <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('testTextarea').value='test 1';">This link will replace the contents of the page with "test 1"</a></li>
</ul>
<textarea id="testTextarea">Content to be replaced</textarea>
```

So my question is: Why does Chrome update the HTML element `body`?

**Edit Mar 1 2:11 AM UCT:**
The following code works fine in Chrome:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("<here comes the ID>").value="test"; true;
```

So adding `true` as the last command resolves the issue. But why? It seems that only bookmarklets behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is expected behaviour

If a bookmarklet is run and its returned value is *not* `undefined` it is standard behaviour for the browser to replace the contents of the page with the returned value. In your example this is "test".

> When a browser follows a javascript: URI, it evaluates the code in the URI and then replaces the contents of the page with the returned value, unless the returned value is undefined.

*JavaScript URIs ([Mozilla Developer Network - void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void))*

### Why does your second version work?

This appears to be a bug in Chrome ([Issue 407505](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=407505)), the same code in IE and Firefox results in the expected behaviour (i.e. the same outcome as the first version).

### What can you do?

- Use the `void` operator. This will ensure that `undefined` is
  returned instead
- Change your second method to return `undefined` instead of `true`

```css
ul, li{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
textarea {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><strong>With the void operator:</strong> <a href="javascript:void(document.getElementById('testTextarea').value='test 1');">This link will replace the contents of the textarea with "test 1"</a></li>
  <li><strong>Returning undefined:</strong> <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('testTextarea').value='test 2';undefined;">This link will replace the contents of the textarea with "test 2"</a></li>
</ul>
<textarea id="testTextarea">Content to be replaced</textarea>
```

Comment: So putting "void(...)" around the code in any bookmarklet should resolve any other issues with return values?

Comment: Should do, as long as `undefined` is returned the contents of the page will not be replaced so the desired action of the bookmarklet should be visible.